# In a GWT application should I use a different event (and event handler) for switching to each View?

Tags: events, gwt, mvp

I'm coding a Menu in GWT that opens a View according to the clicked entry. The problem is I have a lot of different views (~20).

Right now the design is: the menu fires an event using the eventBus, the AppController catches it, adds it to the History and open the right Presenter (passing it the right View).

I'm not sure anymore creating a lot of events like "GoToXXX1" , "GoToXXX2", etc. is the right approach, should I use a single Event with a parameter? Am I doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah im not so sure this is the right way to do it:

I would do the following:

1. create a hashmap with key "#-url", like #view1, #page1, etc. and value the view
   HashMap mapView = new hashMap();
   if your views are not Composite use Widget or whatever the base class is.
2. On the menu, use the  Anchor class and do .setHref("view1"),.setHref("page1"), etc.
3. Add a History.addValueChangeHandler(yourAppController);
4. When you capture a History event, get the value and then do mapView.get(historyEvent);
5. Draw the view you obtain from the hashmap

Comment: thats solution only works if you have one presenter for 20 views. if you have a different presenter for each view, that doesn't work. otherwise you had to make also a map for the 20 presenters. the second problem is, that you create 20 instances of views, witch may never be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `History.newItem()` and `History.addValueChangeHandler()`, after you embed an iframe into your html:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''"
          id="__gwt_historyFrame"
          style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory